# Design pattern for Vector Graphic Editor

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, editor, vector-graphics

What are the best practice design patterns/architectures for vector graphic applications like PowerPoint or Illustrator? Specifically for structuring tool-user interaction and action on complex graphical objects (parent-child relationship, geometrical constraints on shape and layout).

Any thoughts about or experiences with the following:

1. Behavior - Adorner - Behavior Stack/Service - View - View Model [Microsoft](http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=DZzGAAAAEBAJ&dq=7533367)
2. EditPolicy - EditPart - View - Model [GEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Editing_Framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested finite state machines for controllers. Separation of view from controllers (MVC or similar). It always worked for me.

Update: I had some time to read up on your links. Some background: I have been studying and working on these types of editors for 25 years. My advice, nested FSMs as controllers, MVC or similar, might be called a super design pattern, because you can see these design components appearing many times over the years, in different designs, each time using different names for the different components. The absurdity of the Microsoft patent is that the ideas are very old, just given new names. If you look at the other link you provided, you can see there are a lot of similarities (EditPart == Behavior == Finite State Machine).

So the super pattern is as follows: nested finite state machines, as in a Harel state chart. Super states handle common behaviors across many sub states; sub states handle more specific behaviors. A super state can be implemented as a super class, or as a separate object instance. In either case, in the overall application, abstractly you have a current state, which is the sub state. If the sub state cannot handle an input message, it goes to the super state (either just using inheritance or by passing the message to another object in a stack).

State transitions are triggered by input messages. An input message might be a user action on an adornment (and an adornment might be decorated the name of a sub state to invoke). Or it might be a keyboard event. You may see an input message called a command.

Every state will have an entry method, whereby it performs initialization, and an exit method, whereby it reverses any changes not committed. Changes are typically committed using transactions, and a stack of committed transactions forms the undo stack.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the thorough answer!  We setteled with stack of bahaviors (FSMs) exactly as you said - passing events down the stack if behaviors above can't process them.  Currently we have a mix of View and ViewModel, but are moving to separate them and have strict MVVM.

Comment: 2 questions: in what case would you exit a transaction? In databases I can imagine some failure of a foreign key, but what's a typical scenario in graphics? Do you know of any books that discuss this subject?

Comment: The transaction exit depends on the state machine you design. Typically, pressing the escape key would exit the transaction and abort. Lifting the mouse button would exit the transaction and commit. However, there can be other messages causing commit or abort -- perhaps another message comes in that is conflicting. Play with some editors you are familiar with and you can map the state machines, if they are documented. No I am not familiar with any books; my knowledge comes from experience.

Comment: @FrankHileman  do you know any source code example I can look at? what you are describing is exactly what I'd like to implement

Comment: @Alfa07 I know it's an old question but do you know any sample code which can give me a start?

Comment: @MikeFills No I don't have any such code. It is generally quite a bit of code. Just pick inheritance or stack for sub-states. I suppose my answer was not clear?